# Passing Character[] Array in new Character[] statement as Parameter in brackets and saving the characters into the new Object

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function which wants a Character array in the following form:

```
f.add(new Character[] {'A','E','C'});
```

Let's say I have a Character array `Character[] x`, and I want to put each value as a parameter into the new Character object which I am creating. If x contains 'X', 'Y', 'Z', there should be all three chars added when I put x as a parameter into the function like so:

```
f.add(new Character[] {'X','Y','Z'});
```

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as it is, are you able to elaborate on why you need to do this? Why can't you simply call `f.add(x)`

Comment: It sounds like you want to ... clone the existing array into a new array? `x.clone()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    private static Character[] globalChar = new  Character[] {'A','E','C'};
    static void addChar(Character[] ch){
        Character[] tempChar = new Character[globalChar.length + ch.length];
        for (int i=0; i < tempChar.length; i++) {
            if(i < globalChar.length)
                tempChar[i]=globalChar[i];
            else tempChar[i]= ch[i - globalChar.length];
        }
        globalChar = tempChar;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Character[] ch = new Character[] {'X','Y','Z'};
        Main.addChar(ch);
        for (Character character : globalChar) {
            System.out.println(character);
        }

    }
```

The output will be :
A
E
C
X
Y
Z